# ReactJS How to change JSON.stringify value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I Used the following code to append my json structured values to a state variable:

```
var value = JSON.stringify({"id":event.target.name,"amount":event.target.value})

this.setState({temp:[...this.state.temp, value]},function () {
    console.log(this.state.temp);
});
```

And i got the result as:

`["{"id":"1","amount":"10"}","{"id":"2","amount":"20"}"]`

How can i get it restructured as following:

`[{"id":"1","amount":"10"},{"id":"2","amount":"20"}]`

Update: When i removed JSON.stringify like this 
           `var value = {"id":event.target.name,"amount":event.target.value}` i got null array as result

Comment: Remove `JSON.stringify(...)`

Comment: Don't stringify the JS object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are using `stringify` on value (object), that will return a string, then you are pushing that string into state array.

Avoid `stringify` and directly push that object.

Like this:

```
var value = {"id": event.target.name, "amount": event.target.value};

this.setState(
    prevState => ({ temp: [...prevState.temp, value] }), 
    () => { console.log(this.state.temp);}
);
```

**Suggestion:**

Use `updater function` instead of using `this.state` inside `setState` method.

Comment: @Mayank This gives a null array as result

Comment: what is the initial value of temp? also you are using same `value` as i pasted in the snippet?

Comment: Initial value of temp is null

Comment: it should be `[]`, as per my knowledge it should throw error if the initial value is null, check console are you getting any error?

Comment: I have given as `temp: []` in my state initialisation and not null. I just meant null array as `[]`

Comment: it should work, check this [**working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/v60pg2j2/)

Comment: This worked. Thanks Mayank. I just edited your JsFiddle to check.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, no need to use JSON.stringify

```
var value = {"id":event.target.name,"amount":event.target.value}
    this.setState({temp:[...this.state.temp, value]},function () {
         console.log(this.state.temp);
    });
```

Comment: This gives a null array as result

Comment: plz change temp = [] as @mayank suggest. that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify creates a string from JS object. That is why all object is surrounded by quotes within an array.

Try this.

```
var value = {"id":event.target.name,"amount":event.target.value};

this.setState({temp:[...this.state.temp, value]},function () {
  console.log(this.state.temp);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: remove the

```
var value = JSON.stringify({"id":event.target.name,"amount":event.target.value});
```

Option2: 
use:

```
JSON.parse(value);
```